# Call method in sub widget from parent

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method in my parent widget that runs and updates a boolean. Whenever the value is changed, a method needs to be run in a child widget, using the changed value. What is the best way to trigger that action from the parent?

Both widgets are stateful widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from magicleon94 was pretty good, and would have worked if I needed to update a widget with new information. I will probably reference that for some other issues I am working on. For this issue, I needed to run a method to return markers for a mapWidget, based on data from a parent, when that data changed. I found the best way to do that was using a streamController, as outlined by [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142821/calling-a-function-on-an-event-from-another-class-flutter). Whenever I updated the value, I called add on the stream, and then received the update in my child class.

Answer (score 1):

You could either inject the parent's method as a callback to the child or dispatch a notification from the child and then listen for it in the parent.

The latter is a cleaner and more reusable way, since it'll improve your child reusability.

You can check [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-notifications-bubble-up-and-values-go-down-c1a499d22d5f) for a very good guide on how to do it!